# Fallthrough in pattern matching

Tags: c++, pattern-matching, c++17

Recently there was a need to write a matching pattern for catching errors, which it actually copes with. But the only thing it lacks in comparison with the same `switch` is the opportunity to fallthrough. All my attempts to implement this feature have been unsuccessful. Initially, I thought about something like this:

```
matcher(errcode)
        .match(SQLITE_MISUSE    , [] { return test::Fallthrough{}; })
        .match(SQLITE_CONSTRAINT, [] { return test::Fallthrough{}; })
        .match(SQLITE_ERROR     , [] { throw std::runtime_error("XXX"); })
        .match(SQLITE_BUSY      , [] { })
        ;
```

But I failed to implement it. So, below, I am attaching my draft "unsuccessful" version of the code. I would like to somehow implement it all the same, I will be glad for any advice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <optional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <optional>

namespace test {

namespace detail {

struct Void final {};

template <typename T> T operator,(T const& v, Void) noexcept {
    return v;
}

} // namespace detail

template <typename T, typename Fn> struct Match_pack {
    T  v;
    Fn fn;
};

struct Fallthrough {};

template <typename T> bool invoke(T) {
    return false;
}

template <typename T, typename Pack, typename... Tail>
bool invoke(T v, Pack&& pack, Tail&&... tail) {
    if (pack.v == v) {
        auto rv = (pack.fn(), detail::Void{});
        // ...
        return true;
    }
    return invoke(v, std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
}

template <typename...> struct Match_args;

template <typename... Args> struct Matcher {

    Matcher(Args... args) : vs_{args...}
    { }

    template <typename E, typename Fn> auto match(E e, Fn fn)
        -> Match_args<Matcher<Args...>, Match_pack<E, Fn>>
    {
        return {std::move(*this), {e, fn}};
    }

protected:
    std::tuple<Args...> vs_;
};

template <typename... Args, typename... Tail>
struct Match_args<Matcher<Args...>, Tail...> : Matcher<Args...>, Tail... {

    Match_args(Matcher<Args...>&& args, Tail&&... tail)
        : Matcher<Args...>{std::move(args)}
        , Tail(std::move(tail))...
    { }

    template <typename E, typename Fn> auto match(E e, Fn fn) 
        -> Match_args<Matcher<Args...>, Match_pack<E, Fn>, Tail...>
    {
        return {std::move(*this), {e, fn}, std::forward<Tail>(*this)...};
    }

    operator bool() {
        return std::apply([&](auto... vs) {
            return (invoke<decltype(vs), Tail...>(vs, std::forward<Tail>(*this)...) && ...);
        }, this->vs_);
    }
};

} // namespace test


enum {
    SQLITE_ERROR,
    SQLITE_MISUSE,
    SQLITE_CONSTRAINT,
    SQLITE_DONE,
    SQLITE_ROW,
    SQLITE_BUSY
};

auto step() {
    return SQLITE_CONSTRAINT;   
}

template <typename... Args>
auto matcher(Args... args) {
    return test::Matcher{args...}; 
}

std::optional<int> foo() {
    auto errcode = step();
    if (SQLITE_DONE == errcode) return std::nullopt;
    if (SQLITE_ROW  == errcode) return 1;

    bool f = matcher(errcode)
        .match(SQLITE_MISUSE    , [] { std::cout << "SQLITE_MISUSE\n";     return test::Fallthrough{}; })
        .match(SQLITE_CONSTRAINT, [] { std::cout << "SQLITE_CONSTRAINT\n"; return test::Fallthrough{}; })
        .match(SQLITE_ERROR     , [] { std::cout << "SQLITE_ERROR\n"; throw std::runtime_error("XXX"); })
        .match(SQLITE_BUSY      , [] { std::cout << "SQLITE_BUSY\n" ; })
        ;

    std::cout << f;
    return 2;
}

int main() {
    try {
        auto x = foo();
    } catch(...) {
    }
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/sxxPdqj9h)

Comment: Can you ellaborate on what advantage your matcher is supposed to have over a `switch`? From the example in the question, they seem indistinguishable. (now that the code has been embedded, it looks like the key feature is that it's a multidimensional matcher, could you confirm that this is the reason you need the class?)

Comment: @Frank Well, for example, the ability to check several variables at once. But I really don't understand how this relates to my question? Let's just say it's a purely academic interest.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure the baby wouldn't be thrown out with the bathwater with any proposed solution, that's all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check return type of your "case":

```
template <typename T, typename Pack, typename... Tail>
bool invoke(T v, Pack&& pack, Tail&&... tail) {
    if (pack.v == v) {
        auto rv = (pack.fn(), detail::Void{});
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Fallthrough, decltype(rv)>) {
            static_cast<void>( // To avoid warning for clang
                ((tail.fn(), std::is_same_v<Fallthrough, decltype(tail.fn())>) && ...)
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
    return invoke(v, std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vsTErfcWP)

Note, I changed your *"push_front"* into *"push_back"* to have correct order

Comment: Damn, so at least I was close to it. Ty a lot!

Comment: `detail::Void{}` seems unneeded BTW.

Comment: In fact, yes, it stayed because I tried and experimented a lot. I will take it away. Thx

Comment: I thought a little about how I could optimize my code and possibly get rid of the `if` in the `invoke` function, came up with the idea of building some kind of hash table? But I'm not sure how it should work. I am interested in your opinion on this.